# QML Rowlayout how to center text fields

Tags: qml

I need to display year, month and day in separate fields.

I can at least manage the output using rowlayout and text fields.

[image]

What is the best way to get the individual fields closer together without setting fixed widths?

Ideally, the construct should then be displayed centred in the rectangle (picture 2).

[image]

```
Rectangle { id: root; width: 300; height: 100
    
    RowLayout { anchors.fill: parent; spacing: 0; 
        Text { text: "2023" }
        Text { text: ":" }
        Text { text: "07" }
        Text { text: ":" }
        Text { text: "28" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have the RowLayout fill the Rectangle, but center it:

```
Rectangle { id: root; width: 300; height: 100

    RowLayout { 
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        spacing: 0; 

        Text { text: "2023" }
        Text { text: ":" }
        Text { text: "07" }
        Text { text: ":" }
        Text { text: "28" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for soon response, works perfect